# Intellij Java - ImageIcon window runs but no image displayed

Tags: java, image, user-interface, intellij-idea, icons

I am having an issue with getting my image to display within the GUI window. The GUI initiates fine but no image is displayed [window displays no image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz226.png). I have tired various methods with no luck and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

```
package banksystem;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Login extends JFrame {

    Login(){
        setTitle("Cash Machine");

        ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("bank-icon.jpg"));
        Image img2 = img1.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon(img2);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(img3);
        add(label);

        setSize(800, 480); //Sets frame size
        setVisible(true); //Frame will display
        setLocation(350, 200); //Sets frame location
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Login();

    }

}
```

[folder setup within intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPawK.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/images/bank-icon.jpg"));
```

Also, move resources directory outside of the sources root.